# Is there a good way of short circuiting Javascript promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, jquery-deferred

I'm a bit of a novice with promises/Deferreds. Is there a good pattern to handle the case where one might want to short circuit a chain of promises, for both success and error cases? In the error situation, I know you can chain a `.then(null, function(error) {})` to the end and catch an error from any of the previous thens, but what if you want to handle an error in a more custom way and terminate? Would you specify a 'type' of error in an earlier error handler and return it via a new promise, to be handled or skipped in the final error handler? And what about a success case, where you want to terminate earlier in the chain (only conditionally firing off any later `then`'s)?

Comment: `method.success (function (){}).error (function (){})`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, the promise chain starts with a call to some asynchronous function as such:

```
var promise = callAsync();
```

If you are chaining a second async call, you probably do something like this:

```
var promise = callAsync()
.then(function(){
    return callOtherAsync();
})
.then(function(){
    return callSuccessAsync();
}, function(){
    return callFailAsync();
});
```

As a result of chaining, `promise` now contains the final promise which completes when `callFinalAsync()`'s promise completes. There is no way to short circuit the final `promise` when using this pattern - you can return a failed promise along the way (for instance, rather than returning the result of callOtherAsync) but that requires the failed promise to progress through the chain (thus causing callFailAsync to be called). 
You can always fulfill or reject the `promise` from within the callbacks as such

```
var promise = callAsync()
.then(function(){
    if(fail){
        promise.reject();
        //no way to halt progression 
    }else{
        return callOtherAsync();
    }
})
.then(function(){
    return callSuccessAsync();
}, function(){
    return callFailAsync();
});
```

however, this will not prevent calls to `callFailAsync()`. Some Promise/A implementations expose a `stop` method for just this purpose. With stop, you could do this:

```
var promise = callAsync();
.then(function(){
    if(fail){
        this.stop(); 
        promise.reject();
    }else{
        return callOtherAsync();
    }
})
.then(function(){
    return callSuccessAsync();
}, function(){
    return callFailAsync();
});
```

Which depends on having access to the intermediate promise with `this`. Some Promise implementations forbid that (forcing `this` to be window/null/etc), but you can deal with that with a closure.

TL;DR: Promise/A spec doesn't provide a chain short circuit function, but it's not hard to add one.

Answer (score 3):

not sure about jQuery but at least in any Promises/A+ you can just throw:

```
.then(function() {
    if (skip) {
        throw new Error("skipping");
    }
})
//Chain of thens
.then(...)

.then(...)

.then(...)

.then(...)

.catch(function(){
    //skipped here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your use case looks like:

```
promise
.then(a) 
.then(b); // We want to have an option to break here
.then(c)
.done(d)
```

Logical way to handle this is:

```
promise
.then(a) 
.then(function (result) {
    if (something) throw new Error("Do not proceed!");
    return b(result).then(c).then(d);
}).done();
```

If you don't like nesting, you may compose `b(result).then(c).then(d)` as outer function.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem in my application, and achieved short-circuit/cancellation through use of a simple cancellation token object that can be checked for in a Promise's exception/rejection handler callback. Maybe not the most elegant solution, but seems to work well enough without the need for additional libraries or alternate/non-standard Promise implementations

```
const cancellationToken = {};

somePromiseReturningMethod(...)
    .then(doSomething)
    .then(doSomethingElse)
    .catch(err => {
        if (err === cancellationToken)
        {
            // handle cancellation here and return
        }

        // handle "regular" errors here (show/log a message, etc)
    });

function doSomething(dataFromPromise)
{
    // check for whatever condition should result in cancellation/short-circuit
    if (...)
    {
        return Promise.reject(cancellationToken);
    }

    // carry on as normal...
}
```

Comment: Might be clearer to use `Symbol('cancellation')` instead of an empty object as a token too. Great solution!